# How to blend unlit sprite alpha in Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I want a material that won't add alpha of 2 renderers if color's alpha is not 1 when overlapping with the same material. This is to be applied in a UI Image component.

How can I achieve such result with Unity ShaderGraph ?
I use Unity 2020.3.16f1

[image]